# Weighted average to make monthly LST in R?

Tags: raster, r, modis

How to make a monthly LST (MODIS) product from the LST day and LST night, knowing that it is a product of 8 days and some months are represented by four or more pictures in addition to the lack of LST night information.

[image: Fig1]

I try to do it in R, but an average arithmetic does not represent a month, the idea is a weighted average but the lack of information harms the product.